# Sagemaker instance re-start itself after auto-stop. Why and how should I setup the life cycle configuration?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to automate my model by asking sagemaker to automatically execute my procedure script written on the notebook in an instance. So I setup the lifecycle configuration for the instance to auto execute and also call the auto stop instance API in the last cell of my procedure script. However, each time after the instance is stopped, it will then auto re-start itself. Does anybody know why?

This is how the lifecycle configuration is setup:

```
sudo -u ec2-user -i <<'EOF'

NOTEBOOK_FILE="/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/forecast_execution.ipynb"

source activate python3

pip install <packages to install>

nohup jupyter nbconvert "$NOTEBOOK_FILE" --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=python3 --to notebook --inplace --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=7200 --execute &

source deactivate

EOF
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete example by entering also the part of code you used to stop the instance?